# Como usar un checkBoxPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

estoy intentando hacer un menu de opciones con una opción de desactivar/activar notificaciones, tengo un `PreferenceScreen` definido en XML con un `CheckBoxPreference` dentro

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_Notifications"
    android:key="notifications"
    android:title="@string/preferences_notification_checkbox_title"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="@string/preferences_notification_checkbox_summary"
    android:persistent="true"

    />

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Y despues tengo una `SettingsActivity` que extiende de `PreferenceActivity`, pero no se como recojer el `CheckBoxPreference` de los recursos, me da error tal como lo hago ahora

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {


Context context=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    final CheckBoxPreference notifications = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_Notifications");


    notifications.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)
            {
                boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(newValue.toString());
                SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("notifications", checked);
                prefsEditor.commit();

                return true;
            }
        });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la referencia del `CheckBoxPreference`  es precisamente como lo realizas por medio del id definido:

```
  CheckBoxPreference checkboxpref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("<ID PREFERENCIA>");
```

El listener [OnPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) que indicas es usado para detectar cuando los valores guardados en la preferencia han sufrido algun cambio:

```
checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "La Preferencia: " + preference.getKey() + " cambio a: " + newValue.toString());       
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**No necesitas crear preferencia por medio de una `getSharedPreferences`, al definir un id o nombre a la preferencia ya tienes creada una preferencia para los valores en el `CheckBoxPreference`**.